Database not updating when checkbox is checked
I'm new to this language and I'm struggling a bit with implementing this correctly. I have a checkbox, when clicked, should update the database to true and vice versa. It currently creates a new entry in the database, but does not update the isFavorite column correctly. The projectID also seems to not being passes correctly. Any responses would be greatly appreciated!
In the class file:
public bool isFavorite { get; set; }

In the html file:
<div class="checkbox-container">
    <input type="checkbox" 
           id="isActive_@item.ProjectIdNum" 
           name="isFavorite" 
           value="true"
           onchange="toggleCheckbox('@item.ProjectIdNum', this.checked)" />
</div>

function toggleCheckbox(projectNum, checkbox) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var isChecked = checkbox.checked;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCheckboxState", "PrevailSupport")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { projectNum: projectNum, isChecked: isChecked },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    // Optionally, perform actions on success
                } else {
                    // Handle errors
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    }

In the controller file:
public ActionResult UpdateCheckboxState(PrevailSupportModel prevailSupportModel)
{
    try
    {
        string message = ChangeCheckboxState(prevailSupportModel);
        return Json(new { success = true, message = message });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "An error occurred: " + ex.Message });
    }
}

public static string ChangeCheckboxState(PrevailSupportModel prevailSupportModel)
{
    string message;
    var projectNotesDb = new ProjectNoteDB();
    var projectNote = projectNotesDb.SelectAll().FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserID.ToUpper().Equals(RFWConfigMgr.UserID.ToUpper())
                                                                              && a.StudyID.Equals(prevailSupportModel.ProjectIdNum));

    if (projectNote != null)
    {
        // Update the existing record
        projectNote.IsFavorite = prevailSupportModel.isFavorite;
        projectNote.UpdateUser = RFWConfigMgr.UserID;
        projectNote.UpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        projectNotesDb.Update(projectNote);
        message = "Checkbox state updated successfully.";
    }
    else
    {
        // Add a new record to the database
        projectNote = new ProjectNote
                {
                    UserID = RFWConfigMgr.UserID,
                    IsFavorite = prevailSupportModel.isFavorite,
                    StudyID = prevailSupportModel.ProjectIdNum,
                    CreateUser = RFWConfigMgr.UserID,
                    CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow
                };
        projectNotesDb.Insert(projectNote);
        message = "New project note added with checkbox state.";
    }

    return message;
}

private void UpdateCheckboxStateInDatabase(string projectNum, bool isChecked)
{
    var projectNoteDB = new ProjectNoteDB();

    // Retrieve the project note record from the database
    var projectNote = projectNoteDB.SelectAll().FirstOrDefault(a => 

a.UserID.ToUpper().Equals(RFWConfigMgr.UserID.ToUpper()) && a.StudyID.Equals(projectNum));

    // Check if the project note record exists
    if (projectNote != null)
    {
        // Update the checkbox state property of the project note
        projectNote.IsFavorite = isChecked;
        projectNote.UpdateUser = RFWConfigMgr.UserID;
        projectNote.UpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        // Save the changes back to the database
        projectNoteDB.Update(projectNote);
    }
    else
    {
        // Insert a new project note record
        projectNote = new ProjectNote
                {
                    UserID = RFWConfigMgr.UserID,
                    IsFavorite = isChecked,
                    StudyID = projectNum,
                    CreateUser = RFWConfigMgr.UserID,
                    CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    UpdateUser = RFWConfigMgr.UserID,
                    UpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow
                };

        projectNoteDB.Insert(projectNote);
    }
}


What have you actually tried to resolve the issue?

You are doing a "POST" but your controller Action does not have [HttpPost].  If you do not specify a method, then [HttpGet] is the default.  This means that there is no action that matches your ajax call

This is how I normally pass the checkbox and id
1. My model (Note as an example)
    public class Note
 {
     public int Id { get; set; } = 1;
     public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     public bool IsFavorite { get; set; } = false;
 }

2. Controller actions (I have two action Index for displaying the view and about to receive the data from the form)
 public IActionResult Index()
 {
     return View();
 }


 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult About(Note note)
 {
     return Ok(note);
 }

3. The view (where user will input the data)
<div class="row">
    <form asp-action="About" method="post">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">Is Favorite</label>
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="IsFavorite" class="form-check-input" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

4. Submitting the form
submitting checkbox and the Id
5. the result after submitting the form
data submittion
As you see in the picture both Id and checkbox are submitted.
Thanks, and hope that answers your question.
